# How do I determine if adding 2 numbers will involve regourping / carryover or subracting 2 numbers will involve borrowing?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a function that will generate 2 random numbers between x and y (e.g. x = 1, y = 20) which when added will not involve regrouping / carryover or which when subracted will not involve borrowing.

For example,

```
18 + 1 = good
14 + 5 = good
18-7 = good
29 - 8 = good

15 + 6 = bad
6 + 7 = bad
21 - 3 = bad
36 - 8 = bad etc.
```

I want to create a simple worksheet generator that will generate sample problems using the requirements above.

I guess I could always convert the number to string, get the right most digit for each of the 2 numbers, convert them back to integer, and test if one is greater than the other. Repeat for all the digit. Only thing is, that is so damn ugly (read inefficient). I am sure that there is a better way. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: That's a very "base-10" problem...

Comment: Can you expand on that please? I don't understand.

Comment: Well, the question is not so much about numbers as it is about the base-10 *representation* of a number. The answer would be different base-2 or base 16, say. On the other hand, that gives you a clue that the number base is a crucial ingredient in the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;

class Sample {
    static void Main() {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var x = 1;
        var y = 20;
        var a = rnd.Next(x, y);
        var b = rnd.Next(x, y);
        var op = '+';
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {2} {1} = {3}", a, b, op , isValid(a, b, op)? "good":"bad");
        op = '-';
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {2} {1} = {3}", a, b, op , isValid(a, b, op)? "good":"bad");
    }
    static bool isValid(int x, int y, char op){
        int a = x % 10;
        int b = y % 10;
        switch (op){
        case '+':
            return a + b < 10;
        case '-':
            return x >= y && a - b >= 0;
        default:
            throw new Exception(String.Format("unknown operator '{0}'", op));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this code only works for numbers smaller than 50. (You could make it work for number up to 99 by adding an extra check for `x + y < 100` to the `'+'` case.) For solutions that work for larger numbers, see the other answers (including mine) below.

Answer (score 4):

Generate them one digit at a time.  e.g

```
a1 = rand(9)
a2 = rand(9 - a1)

b1 = rand(9)
b2 = rand(9 - b1)

x = b1*10 + a1
y = b2*10 + a2
```

From the construction you know that `x+y` will not involve any carry, because `a1+a2 <= 9` and `b1 + b2 <= 9`.

You can do similar for subtraction.

If you want to restrict the overall range to be [1..20] instead of [1..99], just adjust the range for the leftmost digit:

```
b1 = rand(1)
b2 = rand(1 - b1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Breaking up the numbers into digits is indeed exactly what you need to do.  It does not matter whether you do that by arithmetic manipulation (division and modulus by 10) or by converting the numbers into strings, but fundamentally your question is precisely about the individual digits of the numbers.

- For the subtraction *x − y*, no borrows are required if and only if none of the digits in *y* are greater than the corresponding digit in *x*.
- For the addition *x + y*, there will be no carries if and only if the sum of each pair of corresponding digits is less than 10.

Here's some pseudo-C# for checking these conditions:

```
bool CanSubtractWithoutBorrow (uint x, uint y) {
    while (y > 0) {
        if ((x % 10) < (y % 10)) return False;
        x /= 10; y /= 10;
    }
    return True;
}

bool CanAddWithoutCarry (uint x, uint y) {
    while (x > 0 && y > 0) {
        if ((x % 10) + (y % 10) >= 10) return False;
        x /= 10; y /= 10;
    }
    return True;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at each pair digit in turn, and see if adding or subtracting them involves carries.

You can get the rightmost digit by taking the value modulo 10, x%10, and you can erase the right most digit by dividing by 10.

No string conversions are necessary.